# Putting limits on a matplotlib animation with plt.ion()

Tags: python, matplotlib, boundaries

I'm trying to make an **animation** with matplotlib **without using FuncAnimation**, because it's causing problems with the HTML (ffmpeg). I'm now trying with the `plt.ion()` which is more often used for live plot.

I had no problems making the animation, but the curve isn't really moving, it's the boundaries that are moving most of the time.

I tried the usual boundaries, like set `plt.xlim(#boundaries)` and for the y... but it didn't work. Any clues on how to fix the problem?

Here is what I have done (it's just example code, because the animation that I want to do is the quantum wave function and that code is already kinda messy)

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

a = int(input("render level = "))
tmax = float(input("tmax = "))

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, a)
t = np.linspace(0, tmax, a)

plt.figure()
plt.ion()
plt.xlim([0, 2*np.pi])
plt.ylim([-1.2, 1.2])
plt.plot([], [])

i = 0


while i<a:
    y = np.cos(t[i])*np.sin(x)
    print(t[i])

    plt.clf()
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.pause(1/(a*tmax))
    i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It' not plotting just the boundaries. It gives that impression because the y axis limits are self-adjusting all the time. This is because you are clearing the figure n the while loop, and with it it forgets whatever you had set before.

So you have to repeat the axes limits n the while loop. Try writing your while loop like so:

```
while i<a:
    y = np.cos(t[i])*np.sin(x)
    print(t[i])

    plt.clf()
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.xlim([0, 2*np.pi])
    plt.ylim([-1.2, 1.2])
    plt.title('Time is {}'.format(i))
    plt.pause(1/(a*tmax))

    i = i + 1
```

[image]

Comment: @nobody48sheldor If you have no more questions consider accepting this answer so that it does not show as 'active" on the main site list.